# Can parallel computing be utilized for boosting?

Tags: parallel, boosting

Since boosting is sequential, does that mean we cannot use multi-processing or multi-threading to speed it up? If my computer has multiple CPU cores, is there anyway to utilized these extra resources in boosting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can estimate in parallel each of the weak learners. For example, searching for optimal splits in 'weak' decision trees can be streamlined by utilizing large number of cores.